# Python Elaphe - Barcode Generation Issues

Tags: python, python-2.7, barcode, ghostscript, elaphe

I would like to use `Elaphe` to generate barcodes.

I am working on a 64-bit windows machine. This is on Windows 7, Python 2.7, I have `Elaphe 0.6.0` and `Ghostscript 9.10` installed.

When I run the simple example usage, nothing seems to be happening. The barcode does not show up. When I execute `_.show()`, it hangs but nothing shows up. I have to do a `KeyboardInterrupt` to get back to the prompt. What viewer is supposed to launch when I do `_.show()`? I however see a `gswin32.exe` process in the Windows Task Manager.

Please refer to my Python traceback at http://dpaste.com/hold/1653582/

Is there a way to see the PS code generated? How can I troubleshoot?

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The object returned by `elaphe.barcode` is an `EpsImageFile` (where EPS means Encapsulated PostScript), but after calling `barcode` it hasn't yet run Ghostscript to convert the code into a bitmap image.

You can dump out the code that it has generated by looking at the `fp` attribute - there's a lot of it, because it embeds the full PS library code for all the different barcode types it supports. So it's probably best to write it out to a file:

```
b = el.barcode('qr', 'slamacow')
with open('code.eps') as outfile:
    outfile.write(b.fp.getvalue()) # fp is a StringIO instance
```

In the file you'll see something like this:

```
%!PS-Adobe-2.0
%%Pages: (attend)
%%Creator: Elaphe powered by barcode.ps
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 42 42
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments



% --BEGIN RESOURCE preamble--
... A whole lot of included library ...
% --END ENCODER hibccodablockf--



gsave
0 0 moveto
1.000000 1.000000 scale
<74686973206973206d792064617461>
<>
/qrcode /uk.co.terryburton.bwipp findresource exec
grestore
showpage
```

If you want to see how PIL or pillow runs Ghostscript so you can try it yourself at the commandline, the key part from the PIL/pillow code is this (from `site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py`, line 84):

```
# Build ghostscript command
command = ["gs",
           "-q",                        # quiet mode
           "-g%dx%d" % size,            # set output geometry (pixels)
           "-r%d" % (72*scale),         # set input DPI (dots per inch)
           "-dNOPAUSE -dSAFER",         # don't pause between pages, safe mode
           "-sDEVICE=ppmraw",           # ppm driver
           "-sOutputFile=%s" % outfile, # output file
           "-c", "%d %d translate" % (-bbox[0], -bbox[1]),
                                        # adjust for image origin
           "-f", infile,                # input file
        ]
```

But on Windows the `gs` command will be replaced with the path to the executable.